# Is there a way to use a sound channel on a movieclip?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, flash-cs5, media-channel

The only way i can describe this is showing the code I have already then trying to explain what i want to do..
Basically, I am creating a soundboard game, where at the bottom of the screen I will have a bar which is a movieclip, and I will be dragging other movieclips onto it and then clicking pay, and using an array and .push they will play in order. I am trying to put the sounds onto the movieclips using code. So far, I have this:

```
var snd1:Sound = newSound();
snd.load(newURLRequest("naturefrog.wav"));

var channel:SoundChannel;
snd.addEventListener
```

I am now stuck with what I would put for the listener to listen for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this answer for knowing when sounds have finished loading, if the sound is external:
  [Loading a sound from an external source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977909/try-catch-with-sound-element-into-flash-cs5-as3/4979021#4979021)

Now once you're ready to play the sound and listen for when it completes, that's answered here:
  [demonstrates setting up listeners for sound_complete, as well as looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443686/how-do-you-loop-a-sound-in-flash-as3-when-it-ends/5443790#5443790)

Comment: Thankyou, that's really helpful. I'm not sure if you can help me, but what I'm trying to do is to get the movieclip to play the sound when it is dragged onto another movieclip and the play button is pressed so that the sounds are played in the order they are dragged on. I know I need to use an array and the push function and a loop...but I am lost. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Flash API for Sound](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html) to determine what listeners to add. There are some helpful examples at the bottom of the page.

I assume you'll want to add:

```
snd.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
snd.addEventListener(Event.ID3, id3Handler);
snd.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
snd.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help. What I' trying to do is get the movieclip to play the sound when I drag and drop it onto another movieclip, if that makes sense, I am completely lost, so any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if you can help me, but what I'm trying to do is to get the movieclip to play the sound when it is dragged onto another movieclip and the play button is pressed so that the sounds are played in the order they are dragged on. I know I need to use an array and the push function and a loop...but I am lost. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing the sound reference of a movieclip into an array when user drag it into a particular movieclilp, right? If you do so you can shift an element from array(array.shift, usually this removes and returns the first element of the array).

```
function playSoundInArray(){
    if(array.length){
        var snd:Sound = array.shift() as Sound;
        channel = snd.play();
        channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onSoundPlayed);
    }else{
        //Do something here if there is no sound reference or the array is empty
    }
}

function onSoundPlayed(e:EVent){
    channel.removeEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onSoundPlayed);
    playSoundInArray();
}
```